# How to get data from a database using count, sum and group by in Cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have 3 tables: products, discounts and orders. 
Im trying to get data by using this query:

```
SELECT discounts.product_id, products.product_name,
    sum(products.product_price - discounts.product_discount) as total_Amount,
    count(orders.order_id) as total_Number
    FROM products 
    inner join discounts on products.product_id = discounts.product_id
    inner join orders on discounts.discount_id = orders.discount_id
    group by discounts.product_id,products.product_name
```

this is what I did in `Orderscontroller`:

```
$this->Order->recursive=2;
    $hotest_products = $this->Order->find('all',
        array( 'limit'=>20,
       'fields'=>array('Discount.product_id', 'Product.product_name',
                       'SUM(Discount.product_discount) AS total_Amount',
                       'COUNT(Order.order_id) AS total_Number'
                       ), 
       'group'=>array('Discount.product_id','Product.product_name'), 
       'order'=>array('Discount.product_id ASC')));

    $this->set('products',$hotest_products);
```

and in view:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>

        <tr>    
            <td><?php echo $product ['Discount']['product_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['product_name'], array('controller'=>'products', 'action' => 'view', $product['Discount']['product_id'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product ['Product']['total_Amount']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product ['Product']['total_Number']; ?></td>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, I got an error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Product.product_name' in 'field list'
```

Another problem is that in the view, I dont know how to get total_Number and total_Amount as I dont know which model they belongs to.

**EDIT:** I found out that the code above didnt join the products table as its result was:

```
SELECT `Discount`.`product_id`, `Product`.`product_name`,
SUM(`Discount`.`product_discount`) AS total_Amount,
COUNT(`Order`.`order_id`) AS total_Number 
FROM `project`.`orders` AS `Order`
LEFT JOIN `project`.`users` AS `User` 
ON (`Order`.`user_id` = `User`.`user_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `project`.`discounts` AS `Discount` 
ON (`Order`.`discount_id` = `Discount`.`discount_id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Discount`.`product_id`, `Product`.`product_name` 
ORDER BY `Discount`.`product_id` ASC LIMIT 20
```

But why didnt it include product table while I set recursive=2? the association between 3 talbes is: 
products > discounts > orders. (> means has many).

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure you have product_name column in the Product table?

Comment: Actually, it's in products table.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Product.product_name to Products.product_name so from this

```
'fields'=>array('Discount.product_id', 'Product.product_name',
                       'SUM(Discount.product_discount) AS total_Amount',
                       'COUNT(Order.order_id) AS total_Number'
                       ),
```

To

```
'fields'=>array('Discount.product_id', 'Product.product_name',
                'SUM(Discount.product_discount) AS total_Amount',
                 'COUNT(Order.order_id) AS total_Number'),
```

Comment: I thought, Product in Product.product_name is the name of a Model. Even I change to Products.product_name, I get an error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Products.product_name' in 'field list'

Comment: Use "Product" in singular, not "Products"

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla Do you mean Product.product_name? it still didnt work.

Comment: Is Product associated with Order?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla no, it's not. Please take a look at the post above as I just edited it.